# ansible capturing all results from playbook into one json madness

Tags: json, ansible, output

I finally found a possible answer however it is not working for me and I can figure it out. Tried but failed attempting this: [Ansible append dict results for all hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59325431/ansible-append-dict-results-for-all-hosts)

Im working on a playbook that will run multiple tests against one or more servers of an environment and generate one huge output. I cant seem to figure out how to get results from multiple hosts working.

For example:

```
---
- hosts: "all"
  gather_facts: True
  become: True
  become_user: "{{ deploy_user }}"
  tasks:

    - name: "Check if {{ deploy_user }} can access cron"
      shell: |
        crontab -l
      register: check_cron_access_results
      ignore_errors: yes

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ check_cron_access_results.rc }}"
```

Gives:

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 21 May 2020  20:01:31 -0400 (0:00:02.635)       0:00:12.972 ********** 
ok: [host1.domain.com] => {
    "msg": "0"
}
ok: [host2.domain.com] => {
    "msg": "0"
}
```

I have tried this from the example in the link provided without success:

```
- name: Consolidate result in a single hashmap
  set_fact:
    my_final_map: "{{ my_final_map | default({}) | combine(item) }}"
  loop: >-
    {{
      groups['tag_Role_app']
      | map('extract', hostvars, 'check_cron_access_results')
      | map(attribute="rc")
      | list
    }}
```

I get an error:

```
TASK [Consolidate result in a single hashmap] ***********************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 21 May 2020  20:01:31 -0400 (0:00:00.704)       0:00:13.677 ********** 
fatal: [host1.domain.com]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected failure in finding the lookup named '{{\n  groups['tag_Role_app']\n  | map('extract', hostvars, check_cron_access_results)\n  | map(attribute=\"rc\")\n  | list\n}}' in the available lookup plugins"}
fatal: [host2.domain.com]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected failure in finding the lookup named '{{\n  groups['tag_Role_app']\n  | map('extract', hostvars, check_cron_access_results)\n  | map(attribute=\"rc\")\n  | list\n}}' in the available lookup plugins"}
```

The closest I got was with:

```
- name: Capture crontab result for consumption
  set_fact:
    mynewvar: "{{ mynewvar|default([]) + [{'cron':{'host': ansible_play_hosts, 'rc': check_cron_access_results.rc}}] }}"
```

which gives:

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 21 May 2020  20:25:22 -0400 (0:00:00.693)       0:00:17.011 ********** 
ok: [host1.domain.com] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "cron": {
                "host": [
                    "host1.domain.com", 
                    "host2.domain.com"
                ], 
                "rc": 0
            }
        }
    ]
}
ok: [host2.domain.com] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "cron": {
                "host": [
                    "host1.domain.com", 
                    "host2.domain.com"
                ], 
                "rc": 0
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I am looking for something that I can parse like:

```
{
   "cron":{
      "host1.domain.com":{
         "rc":0
      },
      "host2.domain.com":{
         "rc":0
      }
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the only problem is a typo on one single line for a param you have added: `map('extract', hostvars, check_cron_access_results)` => `map('extract', hostvars, 'check_cron_access_results')` (note the quotes). The optional parameter to `extract` is the name (string) of the next field to look at. See: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#extracting-values-from-containers. And side note: nice solution you found I wonder who wrote it ;)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. In my working sample I actually did have the single quotes, and I fixed above. Nice answer on that link ^^, I definitely learned something new and useful for sure. In my case, I am looking for output that ties the host acted on with the return value that I can use to parse for a report...

Comment: @New2Python can you replace `'host': ansible_play_hosts,` -> `'host': inventory_hostname,`? and try