# How can I save output from multiple remote servers to one dictionary and export to file?

Tags: ansible

I have this playbook to save all my register data from all hosts to  one dictionary.

I was following [this similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59325431/ansible-append-dict-results-for-all-hosts). However I got some errors here.

My goal is to save all patch bundle info from all hosts after patching to one dictionary file.

FYI: My command : `grep VERSION_ID  /etc/os-release` is here just as example to reproduce the Q, In real I am using different adhoc non-standard propriety patching file info.

My final goal will be dictionary like this:

```ini
[inventory_hostname];[bundle]
hostname01; 4Q2022    
hostname02; 1Q2023
```

This is my playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    mydict: {}
  tasks:
  - name: Get dict result
    shell: "grep VERSION_ID  /etc/os-release"
    register: output

  - set_fact:
      result_dict="{{ output.stdout }}"

  - debug: var=result_dict

  - name: Consolidate result in a single hashmap
    set_fact:
      my_final_map: "{{ my_final_map | default({}) | combine(item) }}"
    loop: >-
      {{
        groups["all"]
        | map("extract", hostvars)
        | map(attribute="result_dict")
        | list
      }}
    delegate_to: localhost
    run_once: true

  - name: Display consolidated result
    debug:
      var: my_final_map
```

Error Output from playbook:

```
TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => {
    "result_dict": "VERSION_ID=\"8.6\""
}
ok: [host2] => {
    "result_dict": "VERSION_ID=\"15.4\""
}
ok: [host3] => {
    "result_dict": "VERSION_ID=\"12.5\""
}

TASK [Consolidate result in a single hashmap] ****************************************************************************************************
fatal: [host1 -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: ['VERSION_ID=\"8.6\"', AnsibleUndefined, AnsibleUndefined, 'VERSION_ID=\"15.4\"', 'VERSION_ID=\"12.5\"']. Hint: If you passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True to your lookup invocation or use q/query instead of lookup."}
```

Update:
Thanks it is working now:

```
ok: [hostname01] => {
    "fmap |  dict2items": [
        {
            "key": "hostname01",
            "value": "3Q2022"
```

One more question : if I would like to add another value/attribute :
e.g. "bundle_before_patching" "bundle_after_patching" or "was_server_rebooted" how can I update this ?
In current solution there are no attributes configured in dict.  correct ?

Q2: how to export to csv file ?

I tried below option, but  export is in dict. structure.
Is there any write module like we have read.csv ?
Or simple way : just export it as text file:

```
hostname01, 3Q2022
hostname02, 1Q2023
```

my not best example export script solution

```
    - name: write lines to file
      copy:
        content: "{{ fmap }}"
        dest: "output.csv"
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: True
```

Update:

I tried this to print output, but  still not best, and how to export to file ?

```
    - name: Print records
      debug:
        msg: " {{ item.key }},  {{ item.value }} "
      loop: "{{ lookup('dict', fmap) }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: True
```

Update

tried this to export to file,
problem is that it will always rewrite the file, so I have only last item.

```
      copy:
        content: "{{ item.key }},  {{ item.value }}"
        dest: "output2.csv"
      loop: "{{ lookup('dict', fmap) }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use special variable [*ansible_play_hosts*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables) to [*extract*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-values-from-arrays-or-hashtables) the variable *output* and the attribute *stdout* from [*hostvars*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#information-about-ansible-magic-variables) and [create the dictionary](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-items-from-multiple-lists-zip-and-zip-longest)

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all

  vars:

    fmap: "{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|
                   zip(ansible_play_hosts|
                       map('extract', hostvars, ['output', 'stdout']))) }}"

  tasks:

    - command: grep VERSION_ID  /etc/os-release
      register: output

    - debug:
        var: fmap
      run_once: true
```

---

For example,

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [command] *******************************************************************************
changed: [host1]
changed: [host3]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  fmap:
    host1: VERSION_ID=13.0
    host3: VERSION_ID=13.0

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
host1: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host3: ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Format the output if you want to

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          [inventory_hostname]; [bundle]
          {% for k,v in fmap.items() %}
          {{ k }}; {{ v.split('=')|last }}
          {% endfor %}
      run_once: true
```

gives the expected result

```yaml
  msg: |-
    [inventory_hostname]; [bundle]
    host1; 13.0
    host3; 13.0
```

---

Q: ***"How to export to a readable txt file"***

A: Copy the content to a file. For example,

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/fmap.txt
        content: |
          [inventory_hostname]; [bundle]
          {% for k,v in fmap.items() %}
          {{ k }}; {{ v.split('=')|last }}
          {% endfor %}
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

gives

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/fmap.txt
[inventory_hostname]; [bundle]
host1; 13.0
host3; 13.0
```

Comment: Hi Vladimir, Thanks for reply...its working ! if I want to add also more attributes, with column names, how to do it please ?

Comment: [edit] the question and make the case [mre]. Post the data you want to use, e.g. `output` (it's not important where these variables come from). Also, post the expected result.

Comment: Hi Vladimir, for now this is good for me, I am now troubleshooting how to export to readable txt file

Comment: Instead of *debug* the *msg*, *copy* the *content* to a file.

Comment: Thanks for hint, yes I tried, but I have only last item, there is no append option, right ?